# attributes&class in python using boolean

Tags: python

The requirements for the codes are as below:
Create a class called `Burrito`. This burrito should have:

- An attribute (`is_california`) is a boolean that indicates if the burrito is a California burrito (in other words, if it has fries in it!).
- An instance-specific attribute, (contents) is a list of contents in the burrito.
- A method, (`add_fries`). If there were not already fries in the contents list, this method should add fries to the list of contents and update `is_california` to be true.

and my codes are below:

```
class Burrito():
    def is_california(self):
        contents = []
        if 'fries' in contents:
            is_california = True
        if 'fries' not in contents:
            is_california = False
    
    def __init__(self,contents = []):
        self.contents = contents
        
    def add_fries(self):
        if 'fries' not in contents:
            contents.append('fries')
```

It does not work when I try to test the `add_fries()`, is there any improvements to be made? Thanks!

Comment: `is_california = True` creates a local variable called `is_california` in your `is_california` function and sets it to `True` - you want to `return True` instead (and you probably want to look at `self.contents` and not some empty list you also created locally)

Comment: Thanks! should I put in any values when defining contents?

Answer (score 0):

A shorter one

```py
class Burrito:

    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = []

    @property
    def is_california(self):
        return 'fries' in self.contents

    def add_fries(self):
        'fries' not in self.contents and self.contents.append('fries')

b = Burrito()
print(b.is_california) # False
b.add_fries()
print(b.is_california) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a method to check if the burrito is Californian, you can simply check when you update it (in `__init__()` and `add_fries()`. Like this:

```
class Burrito():
    def __init__(self, contents=[]):
        self.contents = contents
        self.is_california = 'fries' in contents

    def add_fries(self):
        if 'fries' not in self.contents:
            self.contents.append('fries')
            self.is_california = True


# Burrito 1
b = Burrito(['lettuce', 'cheese'])
print(b.is_california)  # => False
b.add_fries()
print(b.is_california)  # => False

# Burrito 2
b2 = Burrito(['fries', 'tomato'])
print(b2.is_california)  # => True
```

Some other answers seem to be doing this wrong. `is_california` must be a boolean attribute according to your question, **not** a method.